# How to update one spinner based on second spinner choice

Tags: android

I have to develop the application based on a spinner.

I have taken the `spinner1` as the product choice and I have to give the `spinner2` the data, which is in that particular product category so I have to update `spinner2` on the base choice of `spinner1`.

I have search a lot but I can get any sure example code or resource for it.

Comment: There're alot of similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492003/dynamic-update-of-spinner2-based-on-choice-in-spinner-1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453580/android-dynamic-spinner-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @user639183, there are lot's of similar questions... however, there some explanation on how you do it:

1. Create member variables for the arrays containing your options to display.
2. Populate your first spinner with your category values.
3. Hook on to the Spinner's `OnItemSelected` event by using `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(...)`
4. In the event listener, populate your second Spinner with the corresponding values.

Example for step 1:

```
private String[] spinner1values = new String[] { "cat1", "cat2" };
private String[][] spinner2values = new String[][] {
        new String[] { "a1", "b1", "c1" },
        new String[] { "a2", "b2" }
};
```

Population of spinner1 as follows:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1values);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

This has so far been absolutely straight forward, if you read the documentation and examples for Spinners!

Next, hook on to the `OnItemSelectedListener`:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // create a new adapter with the corresponding values
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(arg0.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner2values[position]);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // set adapter
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).setAdapter(adapter2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // nothing selected, so set empty options
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(arg0.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[0]);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    });
```

Pay attention, that the order of the arrays in `spinner2values` is corresponding to the order of the category values!

Comment: @Hrushikesh If it works, please mark this post as the answer, thanks.